# jQuery - Check if div has not class after add class

Tags: jquery, addclass, removeclass

I want to jquery check div if it has not a certain class after add class:

Here is my add class code:

```
$('#Test').each(function (e) {
    $(this).click(function () {
        $(this).addClass('Rotate');
    });
```

then, i want to check if #Test div has not .Rotate class:

```
$('#Test').not('.Rotate').mouseenter(function () {
        $('#Test').removeClass('Rotate');
    });
```

but this not working.

Comment: Just a note... ID should be unique on a page. You should not be using .each on an ID

Comment: can you share the target html...

Comment: Looks like you might be having multiple elements with the Id `Test` but the ID selector will return only the first element with the said ID

Comment: Additionally, if you *did* want to hook up `click` handlers on each of the elements in a matched set, you don't need to use `each`. Your code above is equivalent to `$('#Test').click(function() { $(this).addClass('Rotate'); });`

Comment: it was my mistake, sorry guys for ID issue, it was a simple mistake. please read this:

Thanks for reply, but look like i couldn't describe my question correctly, please look [this](http://jsfiddle.net/edJL8/4/) , you see, when you click each circle they will rotating, and then if you mouse over each one, they will stop rotating, but the MAIN QUESTION is: i want only stop rotating on mouse over on other circle not current (or target) circle , i mean when you mouse over on current circle that rotating, it does not affect , then if you mouse over on other, it will stop rotating. @ArunPJohny

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you use classes rather than `id`s (since [`id`s **must** be unique](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute) in the document), it *sounds* like you're saying you want to add the `Rotate` class to elements when they're clicked, and remove it when those elements receive a `mouseenter`.

Delegated handling is probably your best bet for that:

```
// Clicking on a .Test that isn't a .Rotate adds .Rotate
$("body").on("click", ".Test:not(.Rotate)", function() {
  $(this).addClass("Rotate");
});

// mouseenter on a .Test.Rotate removes the .Rotate
$("body").on("mouseenter", ".Test.Rotate", function() {
  $(this).removeClass("Rotate");
});
```

That actually hooks the events on the `body` element, but fires them only when the event travelled through an element matching the given selector. This is useful for when you're adding/removing elements or adding/removing things (like your `Rotate` class) that you use to determine whether to hook an event. Since the test happens when the event occurs, it doesn't matter that there aren't (in my example below, anyway) any elements that match the selector initially; there will be later, which is when it matters.

Full example: [Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/bileloga/1)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Delegated</title>
  <style>
    .Rotate {
      color: green;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <p>Click to turn green ('.Rotate'), mouseenter a green one to remove it</p>
  <div class="Test">one</div>
  <div class="Test">two</div>
  <div class="Test">three</div>
  <div class="Test">four</div>
  <script>
    // Clicking on a .Test that isn't a .Rotate adds .Rotate
    $("body").on("click", ".Test:not(.Rotate)", function() {
      $(this).addClass("Rotate");
    });

    // mouseenter on a .Test.Rotate removes the .Rotate
    $("body").on("mouseenter", ".Test.Rotate", function() {
      $(this).removeClass("Rotate");
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but look like i couldn't describe my question correctly, please look [this](http://jsfiddle.net/edJL8/4/) , you see, when you click each circle they will rotating, and then if you mouse over each one, they will stop rotating, but the MAIN QUESTION is: i want only stop rotating on mouse over on other circle not current (or target) circle , i mean when you mouse over on current circle that rotating, it does not affect , then if you mouse over on other, it will stop rotating. (Sorry for bad english) @T.J. Crowder